# property related to convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I came to know that  even with $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability, it is possible not to have $P\{X_n \in (a,b)\}\rightarrow P\{X \in (a,b)\}$ for all intervals $(a,b)$. Can someone give me an example related to this?

Answer (score 2):

It is even not true with almost sure convergence: choose for example $X_n=1/n$, $X=0$ and $a=0$, $b=1$.